# Метод equals не работает правильно

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться, почему данный код выдает false?

```
public class Solution {
private String book;
public void setBook (String b) {book = b;}
}
class Quest7
 {
public static void main (String [] args) 
{
    Solution book1 = new Solution (); 
    book1.setBook ("Java 7");
    Solution book2 = new Solution (); book2.setBook ("Java 7");
    if (book1.equals (book2)) {
        System.out.println ("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println ("False");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`book1` и `book2` 2 *разные* объекты, несмотря на то, какое у них значение поля `book`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(Это подобно тому, когда у 2 разных человека одинаковая фамилия — фамилия та же самая, но люди разны.)

(Другой подход: Эти объекты разные, потому что в ния возможно независимо изменить значение поля `book`.)

Потому общий метод `.equаls()` выдает `false`. Он не может заранее знать, что вы хотите считать одинаковым, потому он даст `true` только тогда, когда идет о *тот же самый объект* (т.е. когда адреса обоих объектов в памяти совпадают).

Вы можете переписать этот метод в вашем классе, когда вам нужно другое поведение.

---

*Примечание:*

Когда бы вы вместо

```
Solution book2 = new Solution (); book2.setBook ("Java 7");
```

написали

```
Solution book2 = book1;
```

то `book2` бы был тот же самый объект как `book1` - значит, что `book1.equals(book2)` бы вернуло `true`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изменяя значение поля `book` в объекте `book1` изменится значение этого поля тоже в объекте `book2` - `book1` и  `book2` 2 разные имена для *того же самого объекта.*

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в Java `equals` (по умолчанию, если этот метод не переопределен), сравнивает объекты по ссылке, т.е. вы создали два разных объекта `book1` и `book2`, переменные ссылаются на разные объекты, значит они не равны -> `false`. Чтобы это изменить нужно просто реализовать метод `equals`, который будет сравнивать названия книг, и если они равны возвращать `true`, тогда будет работать как ожидается.